# Packaging and deploying a self-contained Python app

Tags: python, software-packaging

I have a bunch of Python scripts that I want to deploy to other machines. Thing is, I want to have everything self-contained and not depend on the other machines' libraries. For example I don't want to request users to have virtual environment and pip as installed in order for my app to work.

On my local machine I use virtual environment with `--no-site-packages` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get everything in place.
The bad news is `virtualenvironment`'s `activate` script has my local path hardcoded into it and using the `--relocatable` option does not help with this situation so I suppose `virtualenvironment` is out of the question?

What I would like to have is something similar to this:

```
base_app_dir:
 - main_app_dir
 - my_init_script.py
 - bin(includes python binary)
 - lib(includes pip installed packages and python libraries)
```

so that I can instruct the end user to just cd into `base_app_dir` and do a `./bin/python -m my_init_script.py` but that means I now need to instruct Python to look into my `./lib` folder when importing packages.

I've tried setting `os.path.insert(1, 'base_app_dir/lib/site-packages')` but this work on per module basis.

Also how about lookup for default Python modules? Right now for example when `import hashlib` it tries to get it from `/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py`. I would like to deploy these default Python modules as well and instruct the app to import them from my custom location.

`Py2exe` or creating a `.deb` file is not an option right now so please try to address my specific question.

Comment: Have you tried [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) ? it does exactly what you need, it will look for dependencies and create an isolated and self contained executable for a particular OS which can run even without python installed.